# HTML inside handlebars script no showing while using ember.js + kendo UI

Tags: javascript, ember.js, kendo-ui, handlebars.js

I'm working on a mobile web app using emberjs. I'm using kendo UI mobile for rendering components inside views, while using Ember.js to work with everything else. The problem is, html wrapped inside handelbars scripts isn't rendering while kendo is active (while new kendo.mobile.Application() is not commented).

Am I missing something?

Here is my code for the view:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="venues">
        <div>
            <ul data-role="listview">
                <li>
                    <div class="test">
                        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="">
                        <h1>Venue Name</h1>
                        <p>calle 7 esq. 10 numero 14. Residencial Rosmil</p>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="test">
                        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="">
                        <h1>Venue Name</h1>
                        <p>calle 7 esq. 10 numero 14. Residencial Rosmil</p>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="test">
                        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="">
                        <h1>Venue Name</h1>
                        <p>calle 7 esq. 10 numero 14. Residencial Rosmil</p>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="test">
                        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="">
                        <h1>Venue Name</h1>
                        <p>calle 7 esq. 10 numero 14. Residencial Rosmil</p>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="test">
                        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="">
                        <h1>Venue Name</h1>
                        <p>calle 7 esq. 10 numero 14. Residencial Rosmil</p>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
</script>
```

Here is my code for the router:

```
apptest.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('venues',{'path': '/'});
});

apptest.VenuesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function () {
        return this.store.find('venue');
    },
});
```

here's the code for the application.js file:

```
var apptest = Ember.Application.create();
apptest.Store = DS.Store.extend({
    revision:13,
    adapter: DS.FixtureAdapter.create()
});

var app = new kendo.mobile.Application();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably should create your Kendo app after view has been rendered:

```
App.VenuesView = Ember.View.extend({
  didInsertElement: function() {
    var app = new kendo.mobile.Application();
  }
});
```

Also you may want to assign your app to the global variable instead to access it later:

```
window.KendoApp = new kendo.mobile.Application();
```